# sub query with sum of two columns

Tags: sql-server

Can you please hep me with the subquery, it gives me an error subquery returned 
more than 1 value and is not permitted.
when I run this independent of the larger code it works, i guess it is selecting distinct or the group by clause uses distinct only however when i add it to the union it does not work. I have column A and column B and I want to add them together to give me a total column

**column A and B**

[image: column A and B]

```
    SELECT 
    T2.GL_Batchno AS BatchNo,
    T2.Creditor_Code AS ID,
    T2.Type AS TYPE,
    cast(T2.PO_Number as varchar(25)) as 'PO Number',
    T1.TranID as Invoice,
    t1.Item_GL_Code as ItemCode,
    t1.Description,
    t1.Quantity,
    t1.Price as Value,
    t1.GST as Tax,
    t1.Price_inclGST as 'Value Inc Tax',
    T2.PeriodNo AS PeriodNo,
    T2.DatePosted,
    T2.UserPosted


    FROM (CRD_InvoiceDetails AS T1
    LEFT JOIN CRD_InvoiceMast AS T2 ON T1.TranId = T2.TranID)

    UNION

    SELECT
    T2.GLBatch AS BatchNo,
    T2.CustCode AS ID,
    CASE WHEN T2.JobType = 1 THEN 'INTERNAL'
         WHEN T2.JobType = 2 THEN 'EXTERNAL'
         WHEN T2.JobType = 3 THEN 'CAPITAL PREP'
         ELSE 'OTHER' END AS TYPE,
    cast(T1.PONo as varchar(25)) as 'PO Number',
    T1.JobCode AS INVOICE,
    T1.Part_No AS ITEMCODE,
    T1.fld_Desc AS DESCRIPTION,
    t1.Qty as Quantity,
    T1.LineTotal AS Value,
    t1.lineGST as Tax,
    **(select sum(t1.LineTotal + t1.lineGST) FROM (FLEET_JOB_JobDetails AS t1
    LEFT JOIN FLEET_JOB_JobMaster AS t2 ON T1.JobCode = T2.JobCode) Group by 
     T2.GLBatch) as 'Value Inc Tax',**
    t2.PeriodPosted as PeriodNo,
    t2.DatePosted,
    t2.UserPosted
    FROM (FLEET_JOB_JobDetails AS t1
    LEFT JOIN FLEET_JOB_JobMaster AS t2 ON T1.JobCode = T2.JobCode)
```

Comment: What Error you have find? If you getting multiple rows then use 'TOP 1' clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the "SUM" and adding t1.linetotal + tl.linegst resolved it.

t1.LineCost + t1.lineGST as 'Value Inc Tax',

Answer (score 0):

You've got a subquery in the second statement that is not correlated back to the outer query because you've aliased it the same as the outer query. I'm unclear on what you're trying to achieve there, but if you need to summarise the total cost by T2.GLBatch I think a better approach would be to SUM over a partition which avoids the subquery issue entirely.

```
SELECT 
T2.GL_Batchno AS BatchNo,
T2.Creditor_Code AS ID,
T2.Type AS TYPE,
cast(T2.PO_Number as varchar(25)) as 'PO Number',
T1.TranID as Invoice,
t1.Item_GL_Code as ItemCode,
t1.Description,
t1.Quantity,
t1.Price as Value,
t1.GST as Tax,
t1.Price_inclGST as 'Value Inc Tax',
T2.PeriodNo AS PeriodNo,
T2.DatePosted,
T2.UserPosted


FROM (CRD_InvoiceDetails AS T1
LEFT JOIN CRD_InvoiceMast AS T2 ON T1.TranId = T2.TranID)

UNION

SELECT
T2.GLBatch AS BatchNo,
T2.CustCode AS ID,
CASE WHEN T2.JobType = 1 THEN 'INTERNAL'
     WHEN T2.JobType = 2 THEN 'EXTERNAL'
     WHEN T2.JobType = 3 THEN 'CAPITAL PREP'
     ELSE 'OTHER' END AS TYPE,
cast(T1.PONo as varchar(25)) as 'PO Number',
T1.JobCode AS INVOICE,
T1.Part_No AS ITEMCODE,
T1.fld_Desc AS DESCRIPTION,
t1.Qty as Quantity,
T1.LineTotal AS Value,
t1.lineGST as Tax,
sum(t1.LineTotal + t1.lineGST) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.GLBatch) as 'Value Inc Tax',
t2.PeriodPosted as PeriodNo,
t2.DatePosted,
t2.UserPosted
FROM (FLEET_JOB_JobDetails AS t1
LEFT JOIN FLEET_JOB_JobMaster AS t2 ON T1.JobCode = T2.JobCode)
```

Although I don't understand why you're doing that at all - can't you simply add t1.linetotal and t1.linegst without doing it as a SUM?

Comment: Wow! It was really that simple add the two without sum worked. The purpose of this is we have debtor table and creditor table I want to pull all data from both only way to do is do a union between the two.